# An 80s sci fi movie about a guy being interrogated in a torture chamber

Tags: story-identification, movie

I remember this one is very dimly. I was recording it on Betamax, it was that long ago. We kept Betamax very late, though, so this was on TV in probably the mid to late 80s. I wouldn't swear it wasn't very early 90s, but probably not. I only watched the first five minutes; I would have been a small kid and wasn't allowed to watch the rest. I've wanted to track it down ever since.

It was live-action, sci-fi, American. The opening scene, or a scene very near the beginning, involved a gloomy, generically sci-fi torture chamber with a guy strapped to a table in the middle, and a genial torturer demanding information and calling for various tortures to be applied. One of them was called "ultra[something] slime." The guy on the table is screaming "no, no," and refusing to answer. It was a fairly standard torture scene.

I remember it looking reasonably well produced, film-originated, gloomy, shadowy, grey in tone, no bright colours. Lancing beams of light. Probably an 80s movie. I felt like it was shaping up to be post-apocalyptic, but I'm not sure. My recollections could be very inaccurate as this is thirty years ago and I was probably eight, so this is a very long shot, but any ideas gratefully received.

I've never seen it since this one UK broadcast at that time, so I'm fairly sure it isn't any of the well-known 80s sci-fi. It isn't Millennium, but it looked a bit like it, production-design-wise.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details. Also, take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Yeah, I got it. I'm going through my brain with a fine-toothed comb, but this is mental archaeology here.

Comment: This looks good enough to be answered imo, one of the [experts](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/topusers) will come along shortly, don't worry.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "generically sci-fi" as otherwise there isn't much sci-fi in your description?

Comment: I'm basing this of essentially a single mental image, but it's in the Aliens/Outland sort of vein. Dark, industrial. Bluish beams of light, like xenon beams shot on film stock built for tungsten light. I remember mid-grey angular shapes the height of the room, light coming between them. Dark in the background. Probably a top light on the torturee. Scraping the bottom of the barrel memory-wise, sorry.

Comment: It couldn't be [Brazil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brazil_(1985_film)) (1985), could it?

Answer (score 3):

This is the OP, not sure how to get into that account now. I'm fairly sure this was Solarbabies from 1986, although clearly I'm misremembering the details as the slime isn't mentioned at the scene is 53 minutes in!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts